# Is Encrypted Token Pattern CSRF protection immune to BREACH attack?

Tags: webforms, csrf, csrf-protection

[OWASP's Encrypted Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Encrypted_Token_Pattern) is a CSRF protection solution, where the token value is a function of time. Would this mean that Encrypted Token Pattern has a built in [BREACH attack](http://breachattack.com/) protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally no, because in most implementations the token is only generated once per authentication (i.e. when somebody logs in). [It is still generally recommended](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/22936/8340) to only generate the CSRF token once per session.

Once the CSRF token has been retrieved by a BREACH attack, then it could be used on subsequent requests in the session. It doesn't matter if the value is encrypted as it is only the ciphertext itself that is required.

However, as a mitigation for BREACH, you could regenerate the token on every request.

[There are some other mitigations here](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/07/defending-against-the-breach-attack). The one I like best is disabling HTTP compression when the `referer` header does not match your domain, or is blank because this will not break any functionality of the system. For high security systems, it might be better to disable HTTP compression altogether for HTTPS requests, because in theory it is possible for any part for a repeatable response to be determined.

Comment: The 3rd option for mitigation in the BREACH document is: Randomizing secrets per request. Encrypted Token Pattern uses time as a parameter to generate the token, which makes every token for every request different. Would that not be randomized?

Comment: Yes, if the secret was different every time. A nonce could be used to achieve this as well as a time based parameter.

Comment: OWASP spec says: _After successful authentication, the server generates a unique Token comprised of the user's ID, a timestamp value and a nonce_. So an implementation must include a timestamp. I guess this means that you answer should be changed to a yes?

Comment: The Encrypted Token Pattern is leveraged in a default implementation called ARMOR in C#. There are currently Java and PHP versions also under development. The default behaviour is to refresh to token on every request. Generating the token once per login is not advisable. Refreshing the token per applicable request ensures that tokens have a much shorter validity period.